# Generate report for mocha with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using mocha with NodeS but can't understand how i can generate report and show to the team what test cases i have created and which are not runnig also how many test cases should i write how to decide this ?

Answer (score 0):

Mocha reporter documentation [here](https://mochajs.org/#reporters)

By default, the reporter is the console output. This output can be modified (as shown in the documentation).

I use [mochawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome) reporter to see results in a browser.
Quoting the documentation

> Mochawesome is a great alternative to the default HTML reporter.

The usage is quite simple: `npm i mochawesome` and you can execute your test with the parameter `--reporter mochawesome`.

I use the following line into `package.json`.

```json
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=testing mocha tests --timeout 4000 --reporter mochawesome --exit",
```

When you execute your test, results will be in a folder named `mochawesome-report` where will be an .html file.

And that's all.

Exists more third party reporters, even you can [create your own reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters).